# How many positive divisors of 7560 are coprime to 15?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

I'm trying to find the amount of positive divisors of $7560$ that are coprime to $15$.

I do know how to find the total number of positive divisors a number has but I am not sure how finding those who are coprime to a specific number. How could I approach this problem?

Comment: $7560=2^3*3^3*5*7$.

Comment: Hint : How many divisors do we have not containing the prime factors $3$ and $5$ ?

Comment: $7560=15\cdot 504=15\cdot 9\cdot 56$ so find the number of divisors of $56$ ...